# Method is considering "self" as an argument variable

Tags: python, class, methods, typeerror, self

I have two classes, in the second class I defined a method that instantiates an object from the first class, assigns a value to one of its attribute, and then prints it.

The problem is when I call the function using:

```
test.Pprint(5)
```

I get the error.

```
TypeError: Pprint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

My code:

```
class node():
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test
    
class test():
    def Pprint(self, x):
        rootnode = node(x)
        print(rootnode.test)
```

When I deleted the keyword `self` everything worked as intended. As far as I know `self` shouldn't be considered an argument. What's the problem?

Comment: `self` is the argument. You aren't passing in `x`. `test` is a class, not an insurance. Call `test().Pprint(5)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist `insurance` -> `instance`

Comment: @MattDMo. Autocorrect is fun :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is python magic. When called from the class object `test.Pprint(x)` its a function requiring 2 arguments. When called from an instance, `test().Pprint(x)` python converts it to a method and automatically adds a reference to the instance as the first parameter. In your case, `Pprint` doesn't use any of the functionality of the class, so it can be a static method.

```
class test:
    @staticmethod
    def Pprint(x):
        rootnode = node(x)
        print(rootnode.test)
```

Now it works either from the class or an instance

```
test.Pprint(x)
t = test()
t.Pprint(x)
```

Comment: That was very helpful thatnks!